# Form validation making field required

Tags: forms, validation, required

I'm a newbie here, I'm working on a registration form and trying to figure out why I can't make the "Name" field be required. Email and everything else seems to work fine. What am I missing? 
Thx

this is what I have for the **signup.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#signup-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this),
    name = $form.find('input[name="name"]').val(),
    email = $form.find('input[name="email"]').val(),
    url = $form.attr('action');

    $.post(url, {name:name, email:email},
      function(data) {
          if(data)
          {

            if(data=="Some fields are missing.")
            {
                $("#status").text("Please fill in your name and email.");
                $("#status").css("color", "red");
            }
            else if(data=="Invalid name.")
            {
                $("#status").text("Please fill in your name.");
                $("#status").css("color", "red");
            }
            else if(data=="Invalid email address.")
            {
                $("#status").text("Please check your email address.");
                $("#status").css("color", "red");
            }
            else if(data=="Invalid list ID.")
            {
                $("#status").text("Your list ID is invalid.");
                $("#status").css("color", "red");
            }
            else if(data=="Already subscribed.")
            {
                $("#status").text("You're already subscribed!");
                $("#status").css("color", "red");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#status").text("You're subscribed! Please check your email for confirmation.");
                $("#status").css("color", "green");
            }
          }
          else
          {
            alert("Sorry, unable to subscribe. Please try again later!");
          }
      }
    );
});
```

});

**html** file has this:

```
<form action="signup.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" name="signup-form" id="signup-form" class="sign_form" >
<label for="Silver">Get Notified</label>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="name"  value="" placeholder="Full Name" class="name" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" class="email" />
    <input type="submit"  value="&#x279c;" id="submit-btn" class="submit" />
</div>
<label id="status"></label>
</form>
```

and the **signup.php** file is:

```
<?php 

$submit_url = 'http://www.domain.com/signup';
$list = 'list010101';

//POST variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

//subscribe
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'list' => $list,
    'boolean' => 'true'
    )
);
$opts = array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST', 'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content' => $postdata));
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($submit_url.'/subscribe', false, $context);

echo $result;
```

?>

Comment: We're talking about HTML `required` right? The HTML part please?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. I've just added the HTML and the PHP codes. Could it be the php?

Comment: thanks for your help, I took another look and realize I was missing another php file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should validate before you post because it seems you are posting to the server then checking the values. It's a good idea to validate before you send data to the server.

Something like:

```
$("#signup-form").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
//use ids to find the form field e.g. <input type='text' id='name'>
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
//this is just checking if its an empty string, add your own validation here
if (email == "") return false;
if (name == "") return false;
//return true if validation passes for the form to submit or do your ajax post here
return true;
```

You could also use this plugin [jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try figure this out first. I think you're right, it might be my php code. I've just added the HTML and the PHP code. If this doesn't work out, Jquery Validation looks great. thx

Comment: thanks for your help, I took another look and realize I was missing another php file.